# Hiding directory listing inside public react directory

Tags: reactjs

I have a `/public/static/images/` folder in my React project and I was hoping that I could hide the listing of what images are in there unless they go to the absolute path.

For example, right now if you go to `http://website.com/static/images/` it returns the following:

```
<pre>
    <a href="KBLogo.png">KBLogo.png</a>
    <a href="icons/">icons/</a>
    <a href="logo.png">logo.png</a>
    <a href="logo.svg">logo.svg</a>
    <a href="test/">test/</a>
</pre>
```

Is there anyway to remove this? I created this application via create-react-app